# Connected/Disconnected events are not received for multiple BLE devices connect

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have a requirement to connect/disconnect multiple Bluetooth LE device, after getting the connect/disconnect event from the native.

`i.e.BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED/BluetoothAdapter.STATE_DISCONNECTED`.

I could able receive all the events like 
`BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTING,BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED`, `BluetoothAdapter.STATE_DISCONNECTING,BluetoothAdapter.STATE_DISCONNECTED`.

If I am trying to connect for the 1st device. But when ever 2nd device trying to connect it gave me only the bonded state not the connect/Disconnect state.

I have register the below mentioned intents to receive the state change

```
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.BOND_STATE_CHANGED" />
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST" />
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.CLASS_CHANGED" />
<action   
 android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED" />
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
```

Please find my received class

```
public class ConnectionReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {

    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(action.equalsIgnoreCase(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED)) {
    int extra = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, 345);  
    Log.d("<<ConnectionReciever>>", ">>>>>EXTRA_Bond_STATE = "+ extra);
    int extra1 = 
       intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_CONNECTION_STATE, 345);    
    Log.d("<<ConnectionReciever>>", 
           ">>>>>EXTRA_CONNECTION_STATE = "+ extra1);
        switch (extra) {
        case BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED:

            Log.d("Bikash---", "bond bonded BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED");
            break;
        case BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING:
            Log.d("Bikash---", "bond bonding BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING");
            break;
        case BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE:
            Log.d("Bikash---", "bond NONE---  BluetoothDevice.BOND_None");
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }      
 if(action.equalsIgnoreCase(
   BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
   int extra = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_CONNECTION_STATE,
    BluetoothAdapter.STATE_DISCONNECTED);

    BluetoothDevice device = 
       intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        Log.d("Bikash---", "--------- Bluetooth A2DP device 
           :"+device.getName()+" address :"+device.getAddress());

        switch (extra) {
        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTING:
            Log.d("Bikash---", "------- Bluetooth A2DP state Connecting");
            break;
        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED:
            Log.d("Bikash---", "------- Bluetooth A2DP state Connected");
            break;
        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_DISCONNECTING:
            Log.d("Bikash---", "------- Bluetooth A2DP state 
                 Disconnecting");
            break;
        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
            Log.d("Bikash---", "------- Bluetooth A2DP state Disconnected");
            break;
        default:
            Log.d("Bikash---", "------- default case 1");
            break;
        }

    }       


}
```